# Static library for DevIL?

Tags: static-linking, devil

I really need a static version of the DevIL DLLs for windows as I need to statically link my program to it. Anyone got one?

I, unfortunately, don't have the toolchain to compile from source :/

thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Is there some particular reason you can't (or are unwilling) to get the necessary toolchain to compile it?

That said, what's wrong with the material available from the download page? All the libs you need to compile are listed right there at the end, and there's an MSVC++ 2008 package all zipped up to make it even easier.

http://openil.sourceforge.net/download.php

Comment: i do not have MSVC++, only have MinGW. I have researched compiling it with MinGW and alot of people have had great difficulties and the author of the library also stated somewhere that he has not tested and is not interested in supporting or helping compile for this platform.

Comment: furthermore, i am actually cross-compiling for windows on linux, and this brings with it by far enough difficulties than also having to contend with a complicated build process on an officially unsupported platform :/